# How to display a template without displaying it inside the layout template?

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, iron-router

Maybe my question is a bit unclear but I'm sure you'll understand with the pictures.

So in my Ironrouter configuration I have the following code:

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout',
  notFoundTemplate: '404',
  loadingTemplate: 'loading',
  fastRender: true,
});
```

the thing is when I want to display the 404 error it insert the `404` error template inside the `layout` template so it's a bit ugly:
[image]

The layout is the menu left and the top bar + the footer. It's the template because everywhere I use this.

So how can I display only the template `404` without putting it inside the template `layout` ?

Comment: You could set the layout on each route and remove the default layout from Router.configure

Comment: But it's not logic to put something everywhere (that means it's the default) no ? @mutdmour

Comment: ya, everywhere except for the 404 page since it's not in `Router.configure`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no clean way to do this, however I have used this hack in the past.  Use a route definition like this where 'errorLayout' refers to a template that is a special layout only for the 404 error.

```
Router.route('/(.*)', function() {
   this.layout('errorLayout');
   this.render('404');
   this.next();
});
```

The hack is originally from [here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/issues/1412).

Comment: It's great, and yes I prefer this one than the method of @mutdmour, so thank you for the input